# Azure ExpressRoute python client

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-api-management

Is there python client implementation for Azure ExpressRoute API ?
Checked https://github.com/azure repo and found no something similar to such functionality.
If there is not implementation what's proper repo to contribute to ?

Answer (score 1):

Azure don’t provide the ER SDK for Python currently. As shown on [official site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/expressroute-howto-circuit-classic/),  the creating and modifying operations of ExpressRoute circuit are via PowerShell cmdlet. However, Azure supports [Rest APIs for ExpressRoute operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn606310.aspx), you can build HTTP requests against these APIs in python.